# Rails Associations Riddle: User, Lecturer, Student and Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I've googled, read the docs, and watched railscast, but I can't wrap my head around this.
Please help. I'm running the latest stable Rails and Ruby 1.9.3, on Ubuntu 13.04.

I have a `User` model, and an `Event` model.
Right now, there is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between the two.

In real life, however, a `User` relates to the `Event` as either a `Lecturer` or a `Student`.
A `User` can be both a `Student` and `Lecturer`, but not for the same event.
`Lecturer` or `Student` are not yet models in my app, and I'm unsure if they should be separate models.
I need help with implementing this logic.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

`Event.first.lecturers` # Should return Users that are Lecturers for this particular Event.

`Event.first.students` # Should return Users that are Students for this particular Event

`User.first.events :as => :student` # Should return Events for a particular User where the 
User is a Student

`User.first.events :as => :lecturer` # Should return Events for a particular User where the 
User is a Lecturer

I'm thinking perhaps a `has_many :through` association might work, but I'm so confused.
Any and all guidance appreciated.

Regards,

Nadeem

Answer (score 4):

You can create two join tables `events_students` and `events_lecturers` and setup models like this

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, :class_name => 'User', :join_table => :events_students, :association_foreign_key => :user_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lecturers, :class_name => 'User', :join_table => :events_lecturers, :association_foreign_key => :user_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :student_events, :class_name => 'Event', :join_table => :events_students, :association_foreign_key => :event_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lecturer_events, :class_name => 'Event', :join_table => :events_lecturers, :association_foreign_key => :event_id
end
```

And then access it:

```
Event.first.students
Event.first.teachers
User.first.student_events
User.first.lecturer_events
```

UPD.

Another solution is to use has_many :through

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :event_assignments
  has_many :student_events, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :event, :conditions => {'event_assignments.type' => 'EventAssignment::Student'}
  has_many :lecturer_events, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :event, :conditions => {'event_assignments.type' => 'EventAssignment::Lecturer'}
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :event_assignments
  has_many :students, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :user, :conditions => {'event_assignments.type' => 'EventAssignment::Student'}
  has_many :lecturers, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :user, :conditions => {'event_assignments.type' => 'EventAssignment::Lecturer'}
end

class EventAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end

class EventAssignment::Student < EventAssignment
end

class EventAssignment::Lecturer < EventAssignment
end
```

I'm using STI for EventAssignment model because it can be useful if you have different logic for different type of assignments. But if don't need it, just use another column name instead of `type` in join model to identify relation type:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :event_assignments
  has_many :student_events, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :event, :conditions => {'event_assignments.kind' => 'student'}
  has_many :lecturer_events, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :event, :conditions => {'event_assignments.kind' => 'lecturer'}
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :event_assignments
  has_many :students, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :user, :conditions => {'event_assignments.kind' => 'student'}
  has_many :lecturers, :through => :event_assignments, :source => :user, :conditions => {'event_assignments.kind' => 'lecturer'}
end

class EventAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Comment: Apologies, I was not notified of your answer. 
And, thanks! 

I tried your first solution. But, both Event.lecturers and Event.students return the same results.

I'm saving lecturers like this:
event_in_db.lecturers << user 

Also, in the join tables events_students and events_lecturers, I tried both user_id and student_id/lecture_id as column. Didn't seem to matter.

Comment: Seems like that first solution didn't work because I forgot to add `join_table` option to `Event` model